# Play microphone through computer speakers Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, speakers, microphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output](https://superuser.com/questions/95384/how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output)
>   [How to output microphone directly to speakers?](https://superuser.com/questions/137963/how-to-output-microphone-directly-to-speakers)

I would like to play sound from microphone directly on my speakers.
How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [How can I redirect sound coming in from the mic to the speakers output](http://superuser.com/questions/95384/how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output), [How to play the sound from the microphone?](http://superuser.com/questions/207310/how-to-play-the-sound-from-the-microphone?rq=1), [How to output microphone directly to speakers?](http://superuser.com/questions/137963/how-to-output-microphone-directly-to-speakers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but if you are looking to have audio output as you record and are using Audacity(something that I'd highly recommend), here is the [preference](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Recording_Preferences) you'd want to enable. It is called playthrough and it lets you hear what you are recording. Does this help?